# CollectionView items animation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating application with chat function. I made simple 'typing indicator' that shows new item in collectionView (Label) with text 'User is typing...'. So now i would like to animate this Label or add some animation like 3 dots that indicates user is typing. Is it somehow possible to make something like this? Any help appreciated, Thank you.

@EDIT
Code below describes my Chat layout:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="content_stackLayout">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <CollectionView
                            x:Name="chat_collectionView"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                            SelectionMode="None"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
                            ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"
                >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="{Binding messageAlignment}" Margin="30,5,30,5">
                                <Image 
                                Source="{Binding image}"
                                Margin="{Binding imageMargin}"
                                HeightRequest="40"
                                WidthRequest="40"
                                Aspect="AspectFit"  />
                                <Frame 
                                BorderColor="Black" 
                                CornerRadius="{Binding cornerRadius}" 
                                BackgroundColor="{Binding kolorWiadomosci}"
                                Margin="{Binding messageMargin}">
                                    <Label 
                                Text="{Binding message}" 
                                FontAttributes="{Binding textAttribute}"
                                x:Name="label"      
                                FontSize="Title"  
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
            <StackLayout 
                Grid.Row="1"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                x:Name="sendMessage_stackLayout"
                HeightRequest="80"
                Padding="8"
                >
            <Entry 
                Margin="10,10,0,5"
                Placeholder="your message..."
                ClassId="message_entry"
                x:Name="message_entry_label"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
                Keyboard="Chat"
                ReturnType="Send"
                TextColor="Black"
                BackgroundColor="#2596be"
                />
            <Button
                WidthRequest="200"
                HeightRequest="30"
                Text="Send"
                FontSize="Title"
                x:Name="button_send_label"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                BorderWidth="5"
                BorderColor="Black"
                CornerRadius="5"
                />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

I've got binding with viewModel which receives messages from another App with SignalR, creates a new messages and adds them to List called "Messages" like below:

```
public class Message
    {
        public string message{ get; set; }
        //public Thickness messageMargin{ get; set; }
        public string image{ get; set; }
        //public Thickness imageMargin{ get; set; }

        public FontAttributes textAttribute{ get; set; } 
        public string author{ get; set; }

        
        public LayoutOptions messageAlignment{ get; set; }

        public Color textColor{ get; set; }

        public double cornerRadius { get; set; }
    }
```

So now when another person in second App is typing, it fires SignalR boolean method that my 'Chat App' receives. If UserTyping = true - App adds new message saying 'User is typing'. I would like to animate it somehow or if not possible, develop another solution for this behaviour.

Comment: How can we reproduce the problem? Could you post some code snippets so that we can try to test on our side?

Comment: @GuangyuBai edited post with some code

Comment: Where do you want the text 'User is typing...' displayed in collectionView?

Comment: @GuangyuBai the best version for me is to display it after last send message, as a last item, as it is standard in many communicating applications.

Comment: I found a method. You can achieve this by using FooterTemplate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout